# how to implement web page mirror with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Put all contents on another web page into a fixed size div.

How to achieve this?

Comment: div?? Can be an IFrame?

Comment: By making content on a page directly dependent on another page, aren't you defeating the purpose of a mirror (i.e. balance loading, faster download, independent copy of a page that could be closed down)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an IFrame HTML element. Otherwise, the browsers' cross-domain policy will be triggered (i.e. it cannot be achieved through javascript, unless you rely on a server-side proxy).

Answer (score 0):

Create a server side proxy to do a http web request. Call your proxy method using an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery (www.jquery.com):

```
$(function() {
    $('#fixedSizeDiv').load("test.htm");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fixedSizeDiv"></div>
```

For more information about jQuery.load, head over to http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback

Comment: Can it be used to load part of DOM and scale it accordingly?

Comment: I mean the same page,but different part.

Comment: Yes, you can use standard jQuery selectors in the url (test.html in my example). So if you'd like the dom in the div with id #coolio, you'd write the url "test.html #coolio". Helpful? Remember to check as answer.